# Array going in wrong direction

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I am following a tutorial and having trouble with an array not duplicating in the direction I want it to. You can see below I have applied an array on an object (which will be a pipe), which I want to go in the direction of the red arrow, yet it goes to the side...

In the video, he fixed this by simply using CTRL+A and selected "rotation", yet when I do this nothing happens?

[image]

Many thanks

EDIT: after making the change, it now goes opposite to the way I want it (which is in direction of the red arrow)? See below

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything unexpected; you have Array modifier set up to array along Y axis which is green one and it happens there. Set 0 for the Y axis and 1 for the X axis below the Relative Offset checkmark.

Comment: Ah solved - I needed to use -1 instead of 1